# Solving DDE using MATLAb

Tags: matlab, ode, dde

```
% declare the variables:
X = 2;
C = 2;
b = 1;
sv = 4;
M = 3;
a = 2;
```

```
% specify the lag:
lags = 1;
```

```
% specifying the time-span:
tf = 5;
tspan = linspace(1,tf,100);
```

```
% history function:
function ph = phist(t)
    ph = 1;
end
```

```
% main function:
function dp = ddefunc(p, t, PL, X, C, sv, b, M, a)
    dp = X*(((C*(p/sv)^(b-1))-(M*(1-(sv/PL)^a)))/(M*(1-(sv/PL)^a)))*p;
end
```

```
% finally, I used dde23 to solve:
sol = dde23(@ddefunc, lags, @phist, tspan);
```

I am getting the following error (bifurcation is the name of my file):

```
>> bifurcation
Not enough input arguments.

Error in bifurcation>ddefunc (line 25)
    dp = X*(((C*(p/sv)^(b-1))-(M*(1-(sv/PL)^a)))/(M*(1-(sv/PL)^a)))*p;

Error in dde23 (line 217)
f0 = feval(ddefun,t0,y0,Z0,varargin{:});

Error in bifurcation (line 17)
sol = dde23(@ddefunc, lags, @phist, tspan);
```

I have no idea why this error is appearing. It is my first time trying to use dde23. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please provide the additional text of the error beyond the traceback (the line numbers)? That said, I'm going to guess it's a "wrong number of arguments" error. Does changing the call to `dde23` to the following fix the error: `sol = dde23(@(p,t,PL) ddefunc(p, t, PL, X, C, sv, b, M, a), lags, @phist, tspan);`?

Comment: @TroyHaskin I have pasted the entire error. Could you have a look?

Comment: My guess appears to be correct. Please try the fixed line of code I gave in my first comment.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Oh, that worked wonders! Thank you so much :)